# Profiling org-capture and improving its performance

Tags: org-mode, use-package, elfeed

My `org-capture` takes about 6 seconds to open up on a reasonably powerful machine, and it becomes over a minute on a cheap laptop. I decided to profile the function and here's what it gave:

```
    2423  97% - command-execute
    2375  95%  - call-interactively
    2302  92%   - funcall-interactively
    2299  92%    - org-capture
    2246  90%     - org-store-link
    1473  59%      - elfeed-link-store-link
    1473  59%       + byte-code
    772   31%      - org-load-modules-maybe
    596   23%       + require
    53    2%     - org-capture-select-template
    53    2%      + org-mks
    3     0%    - execute-extended-command
    3     0%     + apply
    73    2%   - byte-code
    73    2%    + read-extended-command
    31    1%  - autoload-do-load
    16    0%     byte-code
    12    0%   + provide
    2     0%   + #<compiled 0x1e082d37a5ffac44>
    1     0%   + do-after-load-evaluation
    62    2% + ...
```

1. It happens that every time `org-store-link` is called, `elfeed-link-store-link` registered as one of `org-link-parameters` was being `funcall`ed and loaded the whole Elfeed package along with it. So, my self-suggestion was to make `elfeed-link-store-link` to be added to the list only after Elfeed is loaded as whole. I declared Elfeed in my `init.el` through `use-package` with `:defer t`, and none of the other keywords were adequate. How can I achieve the behavior I want?
2. Is it normal that `org-load-modules-maybe` alone takes 2 seconds to execute? The `org-modules` it's looping on seems pretty vanilla with the value being `(ol-doi ol-w3m ol-bbdb ol-bibtex ol-docview ol-gnus ol-info ol-irc ol-mhe ol-rmail ol-eww)`. Thus, I could not see any reason for this taking too long.

Comment: This should only happen at most *once*. After everything is loaded, both `elfeed` and the Org modules should be loaded and do not need to be loaded again. Are you seeing the slow behavior on *every* capture or only on the first one?

Comment: @NickD It only happens on the first run. So, as a cheap workaround I run `org-capture` just for the sake of loading everything.